# What variables are used for the Institutional Activity Index (IAI)?

Tags: market-data, market-making, indicator

I've been looking for various ways to get more information about institutional trade action. Although weekly COT report is available, it's already outdated by 1 week at the time the report come out every Friday. As a beginner in QF, I am interested in knowing what variables (and other factors) are available for trying to better understand the current (near real-time) market, from the *institutional* perspective.

Then I came across some proprietary thing called the **`Institutional Activity Index`** (IAI), from [here](http://ablemarkets.com/platform/2018/03/23/institutional-activity-index/). Where they present a graph like this:

[image]

Now, this is finally interesting, but I fail to see what kind of ingredients are needed to do such a thing, and if, perhaps, there are already indicators or other openly available tools for getting the data needed to re-create this? As I see it, if it is not reproducible, it's probably just a sales scam.

**Question:**

- (a) **What data/information would be needed to get institutional buy/sell order data?**
- (b) **Where would I have to look to get such data?**

PS. I am currently focusing on the currency markets.

---

Possibly Related Questions:

- [Where can I see the bid stack for FX?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37145/where-can-i-see-the-bid-stack-for-fx)
- [where can i get data for foreign exchange order flow](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/where-can-i-get-data-for-foreign-exchange-order-flow)